# confused as how to use componentsSeparatedByString on iphone

Tags: iphone

after nsXml pasring value of my NSMutable array    AB

```
=\n\n\n\thttp://xyz.com/uploads/resto_6298__20091209@1621_250.JPG\n\thttp://xyz.com/uploads/resto_6298__200912099_2_250.JPG\n"
```

now i am doing this to make this url working

```
NSString *sw=AB;


NSArray *strings = [sw componentsSeparatedByString: @"\n\t"];
NSLog(@"what I have %@",strings);
```

but my app always crash and i am getting this error

```
[NSCFArray componentsSeparatedByString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1b28b0
2010-10-05 10:17:31.382 Wat2Eat[2311:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSCFArray componentsSeparatedByString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1b28b0'
```

how to parse this AB so that i can extract exact URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `NSString *sw=AB;`

AB is an NSMutableArray? 
the compiler should print a warning if you try to do this. You tried to assign an NSArray to an NSString. This will not work.

Did you mean `NSString *sw = [AB objectAtIndex:foo];` ?

Comment: i just want to extract exact URL from AB

Comment: wow NSString *sw = [AB objectAtIndex:0]   worked perfectly thanks a lot